# How to hook into a running Java program?

Tags: java, hook

My financial institution has provided Java software to trade stocks. Instead of double clicking the program, I'd like to have it auto run every morning. I've written some simple code in java that executes the program and opens it up.

However when it starts running, I need to provide login and password information before the program is in the state that I want it to be (i.e. connected to my financial institution's servers and providing me real time data). How do I hook into this external Java program so that I can enter login / password in the respective fields and subsequently 'click' the Login button?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is it just me, or does this sound like a really bad idea?

Comment: When you start the program does it not display its GUI?  Is double-clicking an icon really _that_ much work?

Comment: If that is your program and self code why don't you hard code your password and username into java class.

Comment: @vikiiii - now that's a _really bad idea_.

Comment: Use a `cronjob` and pass username and password to the arguments to the main program . @Jim  Is that good?

Comment: @JasonS thank you that's a great way to do it, probably much easier than hooking. If you provide that as an answer I'll accept

Comment: @JimGarrison Well, the trading platform provided auto shuts down every day at 11pm. Waking up every morning to double click something and running my trading program seems a bit repetitive so I wanted to automate that.

Comment: why don't you let us know your IP address so we can help you make sure it works?

Comment: Just remember the risk of leaving a login/password stored in a file, especially as it pertains to online trading.  I personally would rather have to type it in and not risk it accidentally leaking.  Do you _ever_ have any hired help, i.e. cleaning service, contractors, etc. (or even children) that might have momentary access to your system while you're in another room? Is that a risk you want to take?

Comment: @vikiiii -- not a good idea to put username/password in program arguments; they're visible via process viewers

Comment: Proving once again that the weakest link in any security system is the human element.

Comment: @JimGarrison you present a good point about the risk. I think my biggest risk would be someone from the financial institution going rogue and taking my login/password to trade. My network where I run the trading program is secure and I must assume that the financial institution's servers are also secure. I can't really see any way for cleaning people, friends, etc coming into my house, hacking pass my login, opening my java code in a text editor, to figure out my password...Do you have any other suggestions to maybe make it safer? Would storing an encrypted password and using a decrypter work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows. Use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and write a script to Automate the login process.

I am sure there are alternatives of this for other OSs also like AppleScript for Macintosh.